# What is the Action returned by the subscribe parameter of IObservable.Create actually for?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The method definition of IObservable.Create is:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Create<TSource>(
    Func<IObserver<TSource>, Action> subscribe
)
```

I get that the function is called once the observable is subscribed to, where by I can then call OnNext, OnError and OnComplete on the observer. But why do I need to return an Action from the subscibe parameter and when will it actually be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called when unsubscribing from the observer. [Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2009/11/15/introduction-to-the-reactive-framework-part-iv.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is called when the subscription is disposed. It is there for you so that you can dispose any resources that you have allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Kent's answer, calling `Create` is equivalent to calling `CreateWithDisposable` with the action passed to `Disposable.Create()`